# SQL complex contraints

Tags: sql, database, database-design, constraints

I'm working on a little database project and have a problem with organizing complex constraints for this data schema.

[image: Schema]

Here I use BodyPartTag to describe accepted LayerTags in an instance of BodyPart.
The problem is if I'm going to build a BodyPart entity I have no direct constraints from the associated BodyPartTag. I can create a BodyPart called 'Red Eyes' which BodyPartTag is 'Eyes' but I can attach to BodyPart any Layer even if 'Eyes' BodyPartTag accepts only 'Left Eye', 'Right Eye' LayerTags.

How could I reorganize tables to add these constraints? At the moment I use a 'programatic' solution but it requires much coding that seems not correct for this kind of tasks.

Details: the white dot is ONE and the black dot is MANY.

Comment: What is the purpose of layer table?

Comment: LayerTable describes "pieces" of a body part. BodyPart is a logical "aggregation" of related Layers.

Comment: In the example are `Left Eye` and `Right Eye` Layers or LayerTags?

Comment: LayerTags. Layers would be 'Red Left Eye' or 'Green Right Eye' or so... LayerTag is just a 'type' of Layer.

Comment: Please add this to the question and example. It will help in understanding your question better

Comment: I could update the example description if anything needs additional explanation.
The task is to build a valid body part based on rules described in body layer tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with composite keys rather than surrogate keys. It's not necessary a great way to do it, but if you are working with a schema like this it will provide a data constraint as specified.

Firstly, add the 'tag' keys to the primary keys of the `Layer` and `BodyPart` tables, so that the primary key is now composed of two values, i.e.

```
Layer table:    PK_Layer (Id, LayerTagId)
BodyPart table: PK_BodyPart (Id, BodyPartTagId)
```

Then create your `BodyPartLayer` table using those combined keys (2 values each), rather than the current key (single value). The `BodyPartLayer` table becomes a 4 value table with columns

```
-- The two 'bodypart' values have foreign key back to the `BodyPart` table, 
BodyPartId   
BodyPartTagId

-- and the two 'layer' values have foreign key back to the `Layer` table.
LayerId      
LayerTagId
```

Finally, create a foreign key constraint from the `BodyPartLayer` table to the `BodyPartSchema` table. The key will be like

```
BodyPartLayer table: FK_BodyPartLayer_BodyPartSchema (BodyPartTagId, LayerTagId)
```

This will ensure that BodyPart/Layer combinations can only be linked when their respective Tags are also linked. Not particularly pretty, but will achieve your requirement.